# How to use ContourPlot3D with a constraint

Tags: plotting

I want to draw

$$G=G(P,T)=-k*T(1+\log{\frac{(V-1)T^{3/2}}{\Phi}})-\frac{a}{V}+P*V$$

but $V$ is an implicit function of $P$ and $T$, which is 
$(P+\frac{a}{V^2})(V-b)=k*T$

I tried to solve for $V$ and then substitute it in the first equation, but my plot doesn't look as I want it to. It has a region that can't be drawn, as shown in the image below. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
gasG[T_, P_, G_] = -T (1 + Log[(V - b)/Φ T^(3/2)]) - a/V + P*v - G;
a = 1.5;
b = 2;
Φ = 1;
k = 1;
V = Solve[(P + a/V^2)(V-b) == k*T, V]

ContourPlot3D[gasG[T, P, G] == 0, {T, 0, 8/27*a/b*2}, {P, 0, a/(27 b^2)*2}, {G, -5, 2}]
```

[image: contour plot]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that you used to create the figure.  Be sure that it is in `InputForm`.

Comment: G is independent of P so you can plot it directly as G(V,T)?

Comment: Oh,sorry,I miss PV term behind.and I add it up now.

Answer (score 4):

The question's code contains a few typographical errors, which I hope that corrected accurately.  The upper limits on `T` and `P` in ContourPlot3D may be incorrect as well.  Here is what I solved:

```
gasG = -T (1 + Log[(V - b)/Φ T^(3/2)]) - a/V + P*V - G;
a = 1.5;
b = 2;
Φ = 1;
k = 1;
ans = Solve[(P + a/V^2) (V - b) == k*T, V][[3]]

(* {V -> (0.3333333333333333*(2.*P + T))/P - (0.13228342099734997*(18.*P - 4.*(2.*P + T)^2))/
   (P*(108.*P^2 + 32.*P^3 - 27.*P*T + 48.*P^2*T + 24.*P*T^2 + 4.*T^3 + 
   9.*Sqrt[18.*P^3 + 96.*P^4 + 128.*P^5 - 120.*P^3*T + 192.*P^4*T - 3.*P^2*T^2 + 
      96.*P^3*T^2 + 16.*P^2*T^3])^(1/3)) + 
   (0.20998684164914552*(108.*P^2 + 32.*P^3 - 27.*P*T + 48.*P^2*T + 24.*P*T^2 + 4.*T^3 + 
   9.*Sqrt[18.*P^3 + 96.*P^4 + 128.*P^5 - 120.*P^3*T + 192.*P^4*T - 3.*P^2*T^2 + 
      96.*P^3*T^2 + 16.*P^2*T^3])^(1/3))/P} *)
```

The third root of `Solve` is chosen, because it is real.

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[Simplify[gasG /. ans]] == 0, {T, 0, (8 a 2)/(27 b)}, 
  {P, 0, (a 2)/(27 b^2)}, {G, -5, 2}]
```

[image]

The break in the surface is due to a branch cut in the cube-root in `V`.

**Addendum**

A curve similar (apart from scale factors) to the one cited in the OP's comment below is provided by

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Simplify[gasG /. G -> 0 /. ans]], {T, 0, (8 a 2)/(27 b)},
 {P, 0, (a 2)/(27 b^2)}, Contours -> 0, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much to correct my question! are there any method to draw it completely? what I mean is that V should be constrained by $(P+\frac{a}{V^2})(V-b)=kT$

Comment: What do you mean by constrained and by draw completely?

Comment: when solve V algebraically, and choose the real root as its result,it looses some generality.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D` cannot plot the complex roots, although it can plot the absolute value, real part, etc.  If you chose one of these, then all three branches could be plotted.  However, the added branches probably are not physical.

Comment: the real one is physical,the other two are not.I'm trying to repeat the fifth picture of this paper:http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0559v2.pdf.